# Why doesn't string class take in two words separated with space?

Tags: string, c-str

I want to take in persons name using string object. But in my code if I put two part name separated with a space, only first part is displayed. My understanding is .c_str() returns a pointer to stored string with terminal null. Why is there a problem with space. I'm new to C++ and using Code::Blocks 13.12. This is a simplified version of the problem that I have in another program that I wrote.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string sCusName;

   cout << "Please enter your name-> ";
   cin >> sCusName;


   int xsize = sCusName.length();
   char *tempBuffer = new char[xsize+1];

   strncpy(tempBuffer, sCusName.c_str(),xsize+1);

   cout << tempBuffer << " is a beautiful name." << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

When I enter single part name, program works fine. But if I put in two part name separated with space. Only first part is taken in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to read multi-word string using `cin` rather you should use `getline()` the getline() function takes two arguments cin and string variable forexample:

```
   int main()
{
   string sCusName;

   cout << "Please enter your name-> ";
   getline(cin,sCusName);

   cout << sCusName << " is a beautiful name." << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It did solve the problem in this as well in my original program. Thanks again for responding quickly.

Comment: yeah it is similar.